# Duplicating Definitions in bower.json and tsd.json

Tags: typescript, bower, definitelytyped, tsd

I am using `bower` to manage my third-party JavaScript library dependencies for a project. For example, I am using AngularJS, thus I've had to add a dependency on this in `bower.json`.

I am writing my library in TypeScript. Therefore, it is necessary to have access to the typescript definitions too. Thus, I find myself having to use the `tsd` package manager.

This means that the same dependency on AngularJS has to be duplicated in `tsd.json` too.

This is becoming hard to manage as the number of third-party dependencies grows. It is particularly challenging to ensure that the exact same version of the dependencies are imported in `bower` and `tsd`, to ensure the TypeScript definitions accurately match the JavaScript files.

I'm finding this really hard to scale on a hobby project. I am assuming there's a neater solution to sovle this on an enterprise-grade project?

Answer (score 1):

> It is particularly challenging to ensure that the exact same version of the dependencies are imported in bower and tsd

With TypeScript *you generally want to use the latest version of the library*. This is because DefinitelyTyped is *community supported* and people that work on OSS generally work with the latest library definitions (no one wants to spend their spare time on an out of date library).

> I'm finding this really hard to scale on a hobby project. I am assuming there's a neater solution to sovle this on an enterprise-grade project?

Like I said ... just use *n* version of the library with *latest* definition of TypeScript and you will mostly be better off then *just using javascript*.